# Float a Div Inside of Dynamic Article Text

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a dynamic page that based on the parameter query:

> site.com/news/?article=3334 (One Article)
>       site.com/news/?article=3335 (Another Article)

Based on the article ID, the page is dynamically populated with the appropriate article text.

For each article, there should be a div with a secondary image **pushed down** 7 to 10 lines and **floated to the right**, with text wrapped around it.

[Dynamic Div Float](https://jsfiddle.net/mindsecting/8q4LLv5t/22/)

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#article_frame {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.article_title {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article_content {
  font-size: 1.45em;
  line-height: 1.65em;
}

#article_gallery {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}

.article_badge {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.article_badge_descript {
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="article_frame">
  <p class="article_title">Title Goes Here</p>
  <div class="article_content">
    <div id="article_gallery">
      <img class="article_badge" src="">
      <p class="article_badge_descript">Gallery Description Here.</p>
    </div>
    Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here.
    Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. <br><br> Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article
    text goes here. Testing article text goes here. <br><br> Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. <br><br> Testing article text
    goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article
    text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here. Testing article text goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

The Image Gallery div sits at the top, but I'd like to push it down by **7 to 10 lines**, while still allowing the text to wrap around the div itself.

Comment: Have you done some researches ? Tried something that didn't work out ?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of what it looks like now? Are you placing the div dynamically or is that what you need help with

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa I have just recently updated my post with the appropriate code.

Comment: @shadowfox476 thanks, the code snippet is available by the JSFiddle link I have provided above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `div` above the `article_gallery` and include any text you want to be displayed full length there?

```
<div class="article_content">
  <div>
    Top text goes here.
  </div>
  <div id="article_gallery">
  ...
</div>
```

see example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L4owzetk/)